# Android studio not detecting my phone even usb driver installed in studio

Tags: android-studio

I am not able to detect my phone in the android studio.
My system is detecting my phone but it is not showing on android studio only.
I have installed USB driver on my system and also turned on the developer option on my phone.
I am using Lenovo A7000-a model phone and windows 7 operating system.
Can anyone help me out??

Comment: did u enable 'debugging mode' in your phone? and make sure you have ADB driver installed in your PC.

Comment: Yes, I have enabled debugging mode on my phone and also installed ADB driver on my PC, but still, it is not showing my phone

Answer (score 0):

You should have to open phone into developer mode.
steps for developer mode: 
1. go to setting
2. go to about phone
3.click on phone version at 7 time then you will get developer mode on.

After this process you should have to use phone in testing for android studio.

And install the device driver in you system also.

Comment: I have done the above-mentioned steps. But, I can't find my device in the android studio.

Comment: you have to enable "USB Depuration" from "Developer Options" connect your cellphone to computer as a "MTP storage"

Comment: And please follow this : Go to Run > Edit Configurations...
Under Deployment Target Options select Show Device Chooser
Dialog from the drop-down-list